# Windows10 iot core reboot loop?

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I flashed windows10 IOT core into 8GB sdcard and using it on Rpi2. However i get a  bootloop on supply, tried reflashing but unable to fix it and also tried with a 5v 1.5A power supply still result remains the same...please anybody can help?!

Comment: This question appears to belong on [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power supply(**5V 2.5A samsung**) work just fine

Answer (score 1):

if re-installing does not help, then the solution can be to use class 10 8-16 Gb SD card. Ideal is to use [supported card](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm).